# Producing a histogram - occurence of events across the hours

Tags: r, time, histogram

I have a set of data showing patients arrival and departure in a hospital:

```
arrival<-c("12:00","12:30","14:23","16:55","00:04","01:00","03:00")
departure<-c("13:00","16:00","17:38","00:30","02:00","07:00","23:00")
```

I want to produce a histogram counting the number of patients at each time band (00:00-01:00; 01:00-02:00 etc) in the hospital.

So I would get something like between 12:00- 12:59 there is 2 patients etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this (change the example data a little bit, to ensure that the departure time is always greater than the arrival time, it will be good if you have date and time both in the arrival and departure), in the figure below, the time label `10:00` actually represents time from `10:00-10:59`, you can change the labels if you want.

```
arrival<-c("12:00","12:30","14:23","16:55","00:04","01:00","03:00")
departure<-c("13:00","16:00","17:38","23:30","02:00","07:00","11:00")
df <- data.frame(arrival=strptime(arrival, '%H:%M'),departure=strptime(departure, '%H:%M'))
hours_present <- do.call('c', apply(df, 1, function(x) seq(from=as.POSIXct(x[1], tz='UTC'), 
                                                           to=as.POSIXct(x[2], tz='UTC'), by="hour")))
library(ggplot2)
qplot(hours_present, geom='bar') +
  scale_x_datetime(date_breaks= "1 hour", date_labels = "%H:%M", 
                   limits = as.POSIXct(c(strptime("0:00", "%H:%M"), strptime("23:00", "%H:%M")), tz='UTC')) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=1:5) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, vjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

you can have `'histogram'` instead as `geom` in `qplot` to get the following figure:
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.  Actually I have both date and time so for example a patient would arrive at 01Dec2016 17:45 and leave at 28Dec2017 08:00.  I have this sort of data for a year and I am struggling to create a histogram showing the average no of patients in each hour in .  Any help?

Comment: Just reformat your datetimes with `strptime` and the same code should work.

Comment: thanks but seems I can't get the histogram to work even after I reformat the datetimes.  The error is "Warning message:
Removed 373597 rows containing non-finite values (stat_count). 
"

Comment: Can you share your original data sample?make sure that you use `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` while reading the data and use `strptime` with correct format?

Comment: Can someone explain what is the do.call function is doing?  I struggle to understand it even after reading some R help sites.   Any help would be great!

Comment: `apply` returns a `list` of datetimes (for each of the patient the time intervals he was in), `do.call` flattens the list into a vector, since finally we need to find the frequencies (counts) for each time interval.

Comment: Thanks.  If I have date and time for a year and I want the histogram to show the average count, do I need to update the do.call statement?  I assume we would need 365 vectors?

Comment: If you want to show each day's histogram separately then we need 365 vectors, or a single vector with 365 subsets.